# It is [cold] outside so I caught a [cold]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

There is [cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold) out there and it is currently in dual use.

[cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold) as in *it's cold outside* or *cold food*.
[cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold) as in *common cold*.

What to do?

Comment: Feel free to add your own ideas, of course.

Comment: By the way, there are only 8 questions or so tagged with [tag:cold] so the issue isn't as big as this question might make it look like.

Answer (score 4):

Scrap [cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold).
For temperature it is more like a meta-tag and does not add value.
We don't need a tag for common cold either, as it could be integrated with other similar illnesses.

For example: [illness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illness) (3 tagged)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce [common-cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold) for the illness.
Leave [cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold) for temperature.

Answer (score 1):

I think [common-cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold) and [cold-weather](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) would be more appropriate given the questions so far. Those two tags are more descriptive and contextual than just "cold" by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce [cold-temperature](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-temperature).
Leave [cold](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold) for the illness.

Comment: I think "common-cold" and "cold-weather" would be more appropriate. They are more descriptive that way than just "cold" by itself.

Comment: Good idea, want to introduce a fourth answer?